# Jenkins docker plugin and linked slaves

Tags: jenkins, docker, continuous-integration, build-automation, docker-compose

I wanted to be able to start multiple linked containers on demand, with a **restrict where this build run** tag like I do with docker plugin for one single container.

I'm currently running Jenkins inside a docker container and configured a slave cloud using [docker plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) to provide a single slave container per job, this provisioning is done on demand by the plugin.

But now I have some new requirements, example:

- Starting nodejs application container linked to selenium grid container for protractor e2e testing
- Starting a container with a nodejs application linked to a redis server in another container.

Currently, docker plugin [does not support linked containers](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/issues/74) so how should I approach those scenarios?

I know how to start multiple linked containers with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) but there are currently no Jenkins plugins for compose.

I was able to get docker-in-docker working, and thought about having a DIND job with using compose in a pre-setup, but I'm finding this a quite inelegant solution.

Is there a plugin-wise solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docker Slaves Plugin](https://github.com/Dockins/docker-slaves-plugin) new version's side container feature solves that problem now!